# Stuck on the 'Try or Install Ubuntu' screen when booting Ubuntu in qemu emulator on Linux server. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: boot, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, emulation

I am unable to boot ubuntu ISO Image from qemu on Linux Server.

Aim : I am trying to boot a ubuntu virtual machine from qemu emulator on Linux server.

I tried the following commands.

1. qemu-img create -f qcow2 myDisk.qcow2 30G
2. qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm -hda myDisk.qcow2 -m 8192 -boot d -cdrom ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso -cpu host -nographic

I encountered the following error.

> SeaBIOS (version 1.15.0-1)
> iPXE (https://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+BFF8B3A0+BFECB3A0 CA00
> Booting from DVD/CD...
> error: can't find command `grub_platform'.

```
                             GNU GRUB  version 2.06

 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │*Try or Install Ubuntu                                                      │
 │ Ubuntu (safe graphics)                                                     │
 │ OEM install (for manufacturers)                                            │
 │ Test memory                                                                │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 │                                                                            │
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

      Use the ↑ and ↓ keys to select which entry is highlighted.
      Press enter to boot the selected OS, `e' to edit the commands
      before booting or `c' for a command-line.
```

I selected 1st option i.e Try or Install Ubuntu. After selecting this option,this screen is not progressing from here on. I waited for more than 2 hours,still not able to boot ubuntu.

Please help me with any kind of resolution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu and this is my first question in stackExchange. I am sorry, if I am unclear to you. This is the file that I downloaded https://ubuntu-releases.hbcse.tifr.res.in/ubuntu-releases/23.04/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso  from this website https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: What does "Linux Server" mean? Ubuntu Server? Or something else? Since Ubuntu Server does not include a desktop environment (windowing capability), it's unclear what you are looking at, and display failure might be the expected result.

Comment: Yes, I am booting this on a remote server using mobaXterm platform. Can you please provide any resolution? How can I resolve the  display failure error? When I run the same commands on windows it is working perfectly fine and ubuntu is booted,but it gives errors on Linux. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't add new information in comments. Edit your original question instead. There can be no "resolution" until we understand the problem. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is understandable and answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: What does "remote server" mean? What release of Ubuntu is it? Or is it some other Linux release? Or something else? How do you know that your remote server has the capability of running the Ubuntu Desktop installer at all? Remember to explain this information in your question above, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for ubuntu 22.04 LTS

1. In grub, use e to edit `Try or Install Ubuntu`
2. add console parameter to kernel like `linux        /casper/vmlinuz console=ttyS0,115200n8  ---`